# Collecting data with Dynatrace OneAgent or OpenTelemetry

Tags: monitoring, open-telemetry, apm, dynatrace, observability

I am currently thinking about debating using OpenTelemetry to collect data and then send it to Dynatrace or collecting data with the OneAgent.

Have you ever made experiences with this?

My question is, if you think it is valuable to use OpenTelemetry instead of OneAgent? What comes out-of-the-box with using OpenTelemetry and what is missing compared to the out-of-the-box functionalities from OneAgent?

In general, what would you say are the advantages and disadvantages with using OpenTelemetry over collecting data with OneAgent?

Greetings and thank you for your help,

Max Julius

Answer (score 1):

Advantage with OpenTelemetry is price. Paying for ingested traces instead of licensing OneAgents is cheaper.

With the OneAgent there is no configuration required though and you get a lot more then just the traces. You will get full insights to the processes

Comment: Hello Pabi, thank you for your answer! One question regarding the insights. In my case, it would be about traces, logs and metrics. Do you know if there are any out-of-the-box functionalities when using OneAgent, which you don't have when using OpenTelemetry or vice versa? And I guess, that you could get a lot more information with OpenTelemetry too, if you manually configure it, right?

Comment: As mentioned with the OneAgent you get a lot more then just traces. You get traces, metrics and logs and dependencies between them are automatically analyzed and stored.  
A big part with dynatrace is not just getting the data but making it easier to work with the data you get so you don't have to comb through tons of data manually.